# How to fetch GPS location continuously while the user is interacting with the activity and change UI based on that?

Tags: android

I am working on an application in which the UI depends on the current location of the User. So I need to fetch the current location of the user. But this is required only when the user is interacting with a specific activity. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Just search for FusedLocationManager. You'll get plenty nice articles. [Example](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/getting-gps-location-on-android-with-fused-location-provider-api-1001eb549089)